# Is there a special relativity approximation of gravity?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity

The Newtonian approximation of gravity is $\frac{GmM}{r^2}$. General relativity is the accurate model of gravity. But does special relativity by itself provide any update to Newtonian gravity?

I think we should arrive at some four-force called a gravitomagnetic force in SR. Is that a thing? If this, how does this SR approximation of gravity differ from GR?

Comment: SR is defined to be in flat space, so there is no gravity.

Comment: @JuliamDeV that can't be it. Newtonian gravity exists in the flat space of Newtonian mechanics. It's just that the Newtonian interpretation of gravity is as a force instead of as a curvature

Comment: You can use a field of speed vectors and then deduce a field of gamma factor that will mimic the Schwarzschild solution (it can also work for the Kerr solution).